# Built-in support of docker has generated dockerfile with errors

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

My VS 2019 genereted Dockerfile with the next code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj", "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/ProductCatalogApi"
RUN dotnet build "ProductCatalogApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProductCatalogApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductCatalogApi.dll"]
```

And when I run my Dockerfile with command
`docker build .` i receved next:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  77.49MB
Step 1/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
 ---> 014a41b1f39a
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c3eb79db5e63
Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f23ddd06f8f8
Step 4/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
 ---> 006ded9ddf29
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8016eaadf87
Step 6/16 : COPY ["src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj", "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder040062339/src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj: no such file or directory
```

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>ShoesOnContainers.Services.ProductCatalogApi</RootNamespace>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..\..</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

During all my day I am trying to build my image by other way and every time I receive errors. Help somebody, please........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj
```

does not exists from the folder you are running it from.

If the dockerfile is in the same folder as csproj, then it should be

```
COPY ["ProductCatalogApi.csproj", "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/"]
```

It's a bit tricky then, if you are using docker-compose, the path has to be relative path to the docker-compose file you are trying to run